# Make Account Number unique

Tags: validation-rule, account

I thought of adding a validation rule to the Account that would check if an account number already exists via `VLOOKUP`. Unfortunately it seems that `$ObjectType.Account.Fields.AccountNumber` is not working for some reason. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is this even supported?

Answer (score 2):

VLOOKUP can be only done on Custom objects. There is an [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhhyUAB/expanding-the-vlookup-formula)  for which customers requested  the same functionality for Standard Objects where you can upvote so Salesforce may consider this for future releases.

Comment: That explains a lot. I wonder why VLOOKUP only works on custom objects?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a `VLOOKUP`, but you can easily do this with a custom field. Create a new Text field, mark it as Unique, and then create a Before Save Flow that copies the standard field to the custom field. You'll need to do a one-time update to get all values updated, but this process requires no code and minimal custom configuration. You could also write this as a trigger, if you really felt the need, but using a Unique Index is arguably the most efficient way to do this.